# How to find distinct values from array of double type?

Tags: arrays, distinct

I am having an array of double type b[i]. I need to get distinct value from this array. How can i do that?

Comment: You forgot to say what language you're using. (And even if you had, this is probably too vague to be answerable. You should add more details about desired input and output.)

Comment: I want the sum of all unique elements of b which stored in p. b have 5 elements that are random while p have 25 elements. The code is working if b has vaue 0-4, but not for random number.   for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
       { //System.out.println(distinctOrdered);
        for(j=0;j<25;j++)
        {
         //System.out.println(p[j]+"   "+b[j]);
         if(b[j]==i)
          tot=tot+p[j];
        }
        System.out.println("sum is" + tot);
        }
       
       }

Comment: Under your question, do you see the little link that says "edit"?

Answer (score 0):

1 - Sort the array 
2 - Merge/remove the duplicates 
3 - The remaining number of elements are all distinct values

Sorting is not necessary but will make your life easier, as from the question I feel you are in the early phase of learning.

Comment: Which language you are using? Also if this is a homework problem please try writing the code first yourself, then ask for help. This is a community to help each other to learn not to get shortcuts.

Answer (score 0):

1) Java7
 `String[] unique = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(b)).toArray(new String[0]);`
2) java 8:
`String[] unique = Arrays.stream(b).distinct().toArray(String[]::new);`

Comment: My array is of double type..Can u please help me with this..I am working in java..

Answer (score -1):

1) I think u can do this with Foreach, For
2) What is language u use?
3) U need get a unique?